# Units for plasma etching of circuits: A (with degree symbol)/min

Tags: circuits, metrology, nomenclature

**Background**: I'm a statistician working with a design of experiments example regarding plasma etching of circuits, and unfortunately, the author does not define what is meant by the units used for the etch rate ($\mathring{A}$/min). A google search has proved fruitless due to the specialized symbol and the fact that other texts also assume you already know what the $\mathring{A}$ symbol means (which is probably true for those who work in this field, but not for the rest of us).

**Question**: What does the $\mathring{A}$ unit mean in a plasma etching experiment, for "Etch rate ($\mathring{A}$/min)."

Comment: $\AA$ is the symbol for an Angstrom, $10^-10$ meters.

Comment: For the record, the best way to render this symbol here might be with [the Unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/212b/index.htm) (i.e., `$\unicode{x212b}$` --> $\unicode{x212b}$) since there's [an open issue describing the inability of MathJax to render `\AA`.](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/795) That said, it makes sense to leave the question as it is in case people use "mathring" in a search query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anisotropic etching is a linear process, like welding, so presumably the units would be distance per time. Unlike welding it is at a small scale. See [this slideshare](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/minh65/plasma-etching). In this case units are **Angstroms per minute**. One Angstrom is **$10^{-10}\ \textrm{m}$**, indicating the process is on an atomic scale. Since it appears to be used for integrated circuit fabrication, those units are sensible depending on the scale.